# Compilation failure: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7

Tags: java, maven

when using Eclipse and Maven to build a project that contains some simple lambda's for a discord bot, this happenes.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.330 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-04T15:14:13+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project XXX: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/XXX/listener/TextMessageListener.java:[24,54] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /C:/XXX/Main.java:[27,30] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /C:/XXX/Main.java:[33,38] method references are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

The code at the given places in the error message are e.g.

```
client.getEventDispatcher().on(MessageCreateEvent.class)
            .map(MessageCreateEvent::getMessage)
            .filter(message -> message.getAuthor().map(user -> !user.isBot()).orElse(false))
            .flatMap(Message::getChannel)
            .flatMap(channel -> onIncomingMessage(channel))
            .subscribe();
```

I try to execute `Run as... -> Maven install` in the Eclipse Run menu.

There are lambdas used, but they are definitely correct, so this error does not come from an error in the code. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd appreciate it, if the downvoter would explain how to improve, instead of just leaving a -1 :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the problem lies in my configuration of maven for my project. These lines had to be adapted:

```
...

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>bot</name>
  <url>mywebsite.site</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source> <---- to 1.8
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target> <---- to 1.8
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>

...
```

Adapting the pom.xml fixes this error. I'd thought I'd post this fix here, because I didn't find ANYTHING useful to this specific error online, so I thought I might as well add my hard payed knowledge to the internet (I spent some 2 hours until I discovered this by accident, but I'm not very experienced, too).